# datepicker change month not opening in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a jquery datepicker and use it this way:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        changeYear: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        yearRange: 'c-10:c+3',
        showButtonPanel: false
    });
```

When i try to open the Year/Month drop-down, it doesn't open in Chrome. When i try to open it in IE, it opens only on double-click.
How can i fix it to work in Chrome ? and make it work on single click in IE?

i use jquery 1.9.1 and jquery-ui 1.10.3

Comment: Can you make fiddle for this?

Comment: try to give `z-index:99999999`

Comment: You can link the page or is in local ?

Comment: I tried your code on Chrome and IE and it works. I used jquery 1.11.3 and query-ui 1.11.4. Can you try with these versions? This is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deadmask92/L3fxaggh/). @Misha Groiser

Comment: i use angularjs and ignite-ui. now i found that if i remove igniteui-directives inject into angular , everything works fine .

Comment: it is possible that igniteui overrides query's style. Can you post your code? @Misha Groiser

Answer (score 0):

try to change the version of jquery & jquery UI may be there are conflicts between these versions try this will works fine using current version via CDN:

```
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
       <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
          <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
          <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
          <script>
             $(function() {
              $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
                  dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
                  changeYear: true,
                  changeMonth: true,
                  yearRange: 'c-10:c+3',
                  showButtonPanel: false
               });
             });
          </script>
       </head>
       <body>
           <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
       </body>
</html>
```